# My UILabel isn't updating after I change the text value

Tags: swift, uilabel

This is in my viewDidLoad method
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qENLO.png

This is my first post so stackoverflow won't let me post images I guess I'll just have to drop this link.

Basically, I'm trying to assign text from a `json` located here : http://catfacts-api.appspot.com/api/facts using the code above. Ive gone through the values in the Xcode with a breakpoint at the `self.catLabel.text = catFactArray[0] as? String` line, and the `catLabel.text` string has the value I want it to, but the label does not update. Ive already gone over this with a few people and I'm really not sure where the problem is so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try putting the label update in side main queue.

Comment: You're much more likely to get a response if you paste the code into your question as text. It's hard to read screenshots and other users can't copy them and edit them to test the code.

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing any network operation in background and want to update the UI, those UI update should be done on main thread.

Try it.

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

       self.catLabel.text = catFactArray[0] as? String
       self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
       self.catLabel.setNeedsDisplay()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your UI layout updates (label text changes, frame modifications..) must be to the main thread, in your code you make a network call that it's probably launched in a background thread:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://catfacts-api.appspot.com/api/facts")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler : { data, response, error in 
    if let feed = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary! {
       if let catFactArray = feed.valueForKeyPath("facts") as! NSArray! {
          if !NSThread.isMainThread {
             print("Yes , I'm not in the main thread..")
          } 
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
               print("Now I'm in the main thread..")
               self.catLabel.text = catFactArray[0] as? String
               self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
               self.catLabel.setNeedsDisplay()
               self.catLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
          }
       }
    }
})
task.resume()
```